# Is there a javascript event hander for "onPageRendered"?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a JavaScript program that runs when my HTML page has loaded. When the script starts, the first thing it does is to tell me it is running, by writing to the `innerHTML` of an element. But the message doesnt appear.

Previously, I phrased my question badly; and in preparing a code example, I think I have spotted where the problem lies - is it just like an event queueing thing? In my HTML I have

```
<BODY onload="document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = 'loaded'; myTest();"> 
<P ID="p">Progress updates reported here</P>
```

The script is

```
<SCRIPT>
function myTest() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = 'program starting';
  j=0; while (j<1E9) j++;  // representing about 4s-worth of run time
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = 'program finished';
}
</SCRIPT>
```

In that example, all the DOM updates get queued, so the 'loaded' and 'starting' messages never appear.  I can force the 'loaded' message to appear by saying `setTimeout(myTest,11);`.  My original question wondered if there was a way to delay the code till the innerHTML had been updated.

Obviously that doesnt help the more general case of the 'starting' message. I think I can see that this is normal JS behaviour - its a single-thread and it runs till it finishes and then deals with the DOM updates. I guess I just need to break my code down somehow? Or am I missing some clever feature?

Comment: Does [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) suffise?

Comment: When asking a question that involves your code, please make sure to post your code. We cannot help if we don't know what we are trying to fix.

Comment: `load` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: If you are trying to change the `innerHTML` of an element and it doesn't happen but there are no errors in the console, this implies something with your code needs to be corrected. If an element cannot have its `innerHTML` changed (for example, if it is access prior to being loaded), there will be an error.

Comment: This is not a bad question, and I have voted to reopen. Where in the HTML are you including your script?

Comment: Hi @BenAston, the entire `<body>` is the two code extracts above, i.e. the `<p>` element and the `<script>`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code here
});
```

if JQuery is available within your target (browser's) environment and included in your scripts declarations or site bundles.

Check the JQuery's available browser support: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: This is not a jQuery related question...

Comment: @JSONDerulo, the function works pretty much as a "page rendered" event handler in most needed cases. Those who come here, they seek for a method, an "event handler". And I posted an option fitting their needs pretty well.

Comment: There is no sign whatsoever that OP uses jQuery. If OP would actually use jQuery, this would be a good solution, but that doesn't seem the case, so your answer is not suitable to the question.

Comment: This runs at about the same time that `defer` would and a noticable time before `load` would. Since those two solutions are running too early for the OP, this will also be too early.